# hiding xml file in windows form application

Tags: c#, xml

I have a language file and a settings file of my windows application. This files are in xml format and they are shown in the release folder. I want to hide, crpyt or something like that to that files so users can not see either reach my files. 
What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

how does it fit your needs to simply have another extension instead of .xml so the user does not know how to open the files?

you can also set the files as "Embedded Resource" and load from resource so it will be inside the dll itself instead of being available outside as separate file.

other option is to encrypt the file which could be good as well, up to you.

for a very small file, I would embed it.